# Getting multiple java files directory

Tags: java, file-io

I need go through a package with sub-packages that contains some java class file. Can someone teach me how to get all those java class file directories and store it in a String array?

Comment: What does this have to do with Maven and Eclipse - is your question about Maven and Eclipse? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Can you tell us first what you have tried till now and what problem you are facing?

Comment: Well sorry to add, developing in eclipse and using maven as a plug-in.

Comment: can you be more specific, do you want to read the file names to a String array?

Comment: Well I have been going through sites about reflection, but does not seems to be what I need. I need to get the directory of these Java files which is located inside a package with sub-packages in it. Yes I want to read the directories in to a string array

Comment: so, you need to get the directory full path of the current running java class?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getClassArray(File dir, List<String> results) {
    File[] filesInDir = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : filesInDir) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            getClassArray(file, results);
        }
        else if (file.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            results.add(file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

can this work?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't really need the file name, what i need is the directory for example fileA.fileB.fileC.Human.Leg

Comment: In this case, you can just add the name of the directory onto the name. It is simple, because when this method begins, you can get the current directory reference.

Answer (score 0):

The other post will give you all the class file name the below code snippet will give you all the folders which have .class files within

```
public void getClassFolders(File file, List<String> fileNames){
    for (File child : file.listFiles()) {
        if(child.isDirectory()){
            getClassFolders(child, fileNames);
        } else if(child.getName().endsWith(".class")){
            fileNames.add(file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```